# Large navigation bar in detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, uinavigationbar

In storyboard I have `NavigationController` connected with `FirstTableVC` segue to `SecondTableVC`. I want to in all my controllers I have large navigation bar. But when I scroll down in `FirstTableVC` and go to `SecondTableVC` my navigation bar not large. How to fix it?

code in `FirstTableVC`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        title = "FirstTableVC"
    }
```

code in `SecondTableVC`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "SecondTableVC"
    }
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: simply, set a large font label with a constraint to the second VC nav bar and do not set the title for the second VC.

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi doesn't help

Comment: No, it will work perfectly, try it.

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi Maybe I misunderstood something? I should change code in `viewDidLoad` like this `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` and `self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always` or something else?

Comment: No, I mean to add a label in the storyboard bottom to nav bar rather than playing with the nav bar

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi like this - https://ibb.co/ZG6kddy?

Comment: Exactly! Try and I will be in touch!

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi nothing.... doesn't work

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi Could you please share a simple Xcode project that I would launch and figure out what I am doing wrong?